# How to unbind Alt + ` (Backtick) on Windows 10?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, shortcuts, hotkeys

In Dota 2, there's something called Smart Double Tap, making Alt + Hotkey to work as if I've double tapped the Hotkey, and I have the Hotkey set as backtick `. But it seems like it's conflicting with Windows Default Hotkey and the smart double tap isn't working on that hotkey. I have another shortcut as space and smart double tap is working fine on that one.

Comment: The key combination Alt+` does nothing on Windows. Please explain more your problem.

Comment: I would say that it's a Dota 2 specific issue but it works just fine on Linux and I was on Arch to be exact. I don't know if Dota 2 is different for Windows. I've tried Discord's Game Overlay to Alt + ` and it works just fine. So I think it's just Dota 2 issue?

Comment: Are you perhaps using the US international keyboard? Or which one?

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with [*changing between windows of the same program*](https://github.com/akiver/AltBacktick).